# How to describe this relationship in django's model?

Tags: python, database, django

user table:

```
   --------------------
   | id | name | age |
   --------------------
   |    |      |     |
   --------------------
```

model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

pet table:

```
   --------------------
   | id | name | intro |
   --------------------
   |    |      |       |
   --------------------
```

model:

```
class Pet(models.Model):  
    species = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    intro = models.TextField()
```

now I want to describe this relation:
a user can have several pets(with unique species), and I want to store the time when the user got that pet. it should looks like this in database:

```
   --------------------------------
   | id | user_id | pet_id | since |
   --------------------------------
   |    |         |        |       |
   --------------------------------
```

but I don't know how to describe it in django's model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a "through" model. Basically, you define your own intermediary table instead of having Django do it for you automatically:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    pets = models.ManyToManyField(Pet, through='UserPet')

class UserPet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet)
    since = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: is that line in User necessary?

Comment: The necessary part is the `through='UserPet'` wherever the many-to-many relationship is defined. If it's on the `Pet`, you could easily do `users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserPet')`

Comment: I mean I think if there is no pets = models.ManyToManyField(Pet, through='UserPet'), this should also work. is that true?

Comment: You can access the `UserPet` model directly, yes, but it's not good form. Setting up the M2M relationship buys you a lot of utility that you lose otherwise, and when Django 1.4 hits, you'll be able to benefit from improved database optimization through the new `prefetch_related` method (basically `select_related` that works with many-to-many fields).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class UsersPet(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    since = models.DateTime()
```